# Sencha ExtJS 5 Draw Package examples not working - TypeError

Tags: extjs, draw, extjs5

For some reason, the extjs 5 drawing package (Ext.draw.*) examples are not showing up after clicking the "Live Preview" button.  You will get an error.  What can be causing this?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/drawing.html

Click on any of the hyperlinks.

**Google Chrome Error:**

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

**Mozilla Firefox Error:**

```
TypeError: c is not a constructor
```

**Internet Explorer 8:**

```
TypeError: Object expected
```

Comment: Did you create a bug? Can you post a link here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/widget/draw.js is causing a 404. You should file a bug in the Sencha forums http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?130-Ext-5-Bugs

Related issues:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?258845
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?285309